# Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type. Don't work in newer version

Tags: arrays, matlab, types

```
    function [LIMP,n] = vvod
    clear all;
    P = dir('*.txt');% filepath
    n = length(P);% number of files
    for i=1:n
    FI=P(i).name;
    fopen(FI);
    LIMP = importdata(FI);
    Data(:,:,i)=LIMP.data;% dont work on Matlab 2023, but work on Matlab 2017
    clear ('LIMP','FI');
    end
    end
```

Error:

```
    Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
    Error in vvod (line 9)
    Data(:,:,i)=LIMP.data;
```

There are 5 text files in the folder, each file has 6 columns with double data, when opened I want to collect them into a single array.
Code work in Matlab 2017, but don't work in Matlab 2023

Comment: If it is a text format, then why not just read it with `readtable`? I remember importdata had a weird output depending on the format, so the field `.data` doesn't always exist

Comment: `importdata` defers to helper functions, depending on the file type. You might have different helper functions in your two different MATLAB versions. Or you might have been reading a different file in the two different MATLAB versions? This is easier to help with if you provide a [mre].